# Корябать и карябать - в чём разница значений?

Tags: этимология

"Корябать" и "карябать" - в чём разница значений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написание *"к**о**рябять"* однозначно правильное, в то время как *"к**а**рябать"* встречается только в некоторых словарях. А так, если считать, что возможны оба написания, ***разницы в значениях никакой нет.***